# How to handle hidden elements with a single selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have html page something like this:

```
<div ng-show="abc ng-hide'">
  ....
  <select ng-model="failure">
   ....
  </select>
</div>
<div ng-show="abc">
 ...
  <select ng-model="failure">
   ...
  </select>
</div>
```

How can I have a single selector which can handle both the Select elements. I need to get the top div when it is not hidden and bottom div otherwise. I tried something like this.

```
By.xpath("//div[not(contains(@class,'ng-hide'))]//select[@ng-model='failure'])
```

Comment: `//div[not(contains(@class,'ng-hide'))]//select[@ng-model='failure']` sounds good. What happens - any errors?

Comment: its not able to receive the click which I tried to click or get the text in the select

Comment: Is the bottom div the second div in your example?

Comment: @FlorentB. Yes. One of the div's is visible to the user and I should be able to get the select element from that.

Comment: Ok, this xpath matches your requirements: //div[@ng-show][.//select[@ng-model='failure']]